# TableView reloadData lags on rotation

Tags: ios, uitableview, rotation

In my `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` method, I have the following:

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) {
    if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
        _headerImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, 50);
        NSURLRequest *_request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Shared LogoLandPhoneRet]]];
        [_headerImage setImageWithURLRequest:_request andDefaultImageName:nil andUserData:nil target:self sucessful:nil failed:nil];
    } else {
        _headerImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, 50);
        NSURLRequest *_request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Shared LogoLandPhone]]];
        [_headerImage setImageWithURLRequest:_request andDefaultImageName:nil andUserData:nil target:self sucessful:nil failed:nil];
    }
} else {
    if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
        _headerImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 50);
        NSURLRequest *_request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Shared LogoPortPhoneRet]]];
        [_headerImage setImageWithURLRequest:_request andDefaultImageName:nil andUserData:nil target:self sucessful:nil failed:nil];
    } else {
        _headerImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 50);
        NSURLRequest *_request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Shared LogoPortPhone]]];
        [_headerImage setImageWithURLRequest:_request andDefaultImageName:nil andUserData:nil target:self sucessful:nil failed:nil];
    }
}

//    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(doTable) toTarget:self withObject:NULL];
[_feedTable reloadData];
}
```

However, when I now rotate my device, it lags and takes about 2-3 seconds to actually rotate. Any advice on why this might be?

Comment: Don't reload it in `willAnimate`. Reload the table in `didRotate`

Comment: I think it's not the best idea. When using `willAnimate...`, the rotation will be animated and therefore feel smoother to the user.

Answer (score 0):

it lags or it freezes the interface?  my guess is that the request freezes the interface so you shoud try making the request asynchronous or try making a cache before..